# Unable to download R packages

Tags: r

I am using R 3.4.3 on windows 7 ( 32 bit).

**Whenever I am trying to download any file using "R Studio"** 
from say https":// ... site

its not getting downloaded.
I am getting the following error.

```
> library(downloader)
> url <- "http://raw.githubusercontent.com/genomicsclass/dagdata/master/inst/extdata/mice_pheno.csv"
> filename <- "mice_pheno.csv"
> download(url,destfile=filename) 
trying URL 'http://raw.githubusercontent.com/genomicsclass/dagdata/master/inst/extdata/mice_pheno.csv'
Error in download.file(url, method = method, ...) : 
  cannot open URL 'http://raw.githubusercontent.com/genomicsclass/dagdata/master/inst/extdata/mice_pheno.csv'
```

Also when I try to install a new packages using R Studio
its not happening.

In both the cases, downloading of file and installing packages is happening thru R without throwing any error.

please help

Regards
Partha

Comment: Why are you using the `downloader` package?  R has built-in download capabilities in the `download.file()` function.

Comment: Not able to reproduce error -- I am able to access the URL and download the file with `download.file()`. What happens when you enter the URL into a web browser? I am able to see the file this way.

Comment: I have tried the the changes using download.file(). I am still getting the error.

Comment: No download of file or installation of packages is happening in RStudio.